# How do I set up DomainKeys/DKIM and Sender ID

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dkim, email

I have searched far and wide for a guide on how to setup DomainKeys/DKIM and Sender ID. I understand there are text records you add to your DNS, but I cannot find out how to create theses, specifically how do I generate the keys.

Does anybody know of a step by step guide on this process?

Muchly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

There are recipes for the most popular SMTP servers, just google for it:

- [Exim](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/implementing-dkim-with-exim/)
- [Postfix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DKIM)

You can test your setup using:

- http://dkimcore.org/tools/
- http://www.mxtoolbox.com
- Sending a mail to gmail and/or yahoo accounts and checking the message headers

Comment: Thanks for the links. Made me realise that it was server dependant on what process to use. I found [this](http://blog.mixu.net/2009/11/03/setting-up-spf-senderid-and-dkim-on-centos-5-3-using-sendmail/) which was exactly what I needed...

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, its rather specific to what modules you use and server type etc. I am using centos machine with sendmail. [This guide](http://blog.mixu.net/2009/11/03/setting-up-spf-senderid-and-dkim-on-centos-5-3-using-sendmail/) was exactly what I was after.